# Stopping Thrift TSimpleserver with deconstructor function

Tags: c++, boost, mfc, thrift

I have a separate class to handle my Thrift `TSimpleServer`. Since the `serve()` function blocks I'm calling it in a separate thread from my main functions. Now my main problem is even though I can get the server running, I can't find a way to exit it gracefully. I've tried calling the `stop()` in the deconstruct but it doesn't work and I have to assume it's because I have to re-declare an new `TSImpleServer` object in the deconstruct so I can access `stop()`. I can't for the life of me find a way to globally or at least in the header file declare and initialize on instance of `TSimpleServer`. So hopefully some one can help me `stop()` this server an exit gracefully.

Code:

Header

```
typedef boost::thread m_thread;

class ServerThread
{
public:

    m_thread thread_t;

    ServerThread();
    ~ServerThread(void);
    void Run();
};
```

cpp

```
boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocol_t(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());
boost::shared_ptr <ServerHandler> handler(new ServerHandler());
boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor_t(new ServerProcessor(handler));
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> server_transport_t(new TServerSocket(9090));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transport_factory_t(new TBufferedTransportFactory());

ServerThread::ServerThread()
{
    thread_t = boost::thread(&ServerThread::Run,this);
}

ServerThread::~ServerThread(void)
{
    TSimpleServer server(processor_t, 
                         server_transport_t, 
                         transport_factory_t, 
                         protocol_t);

    server.stop();

    thread_t.join();
}

void ServerThread::Run()
{
    TSimpleServer server(processor_t, 
                         server_transport_t, 
                         transport_factory_t, 
                         protocol_t);

    server.serve();
}
```

Comment: Why do you reinstantiate the `TSimpleServer` object in `~ServerThread()`?

Comment: Cause I'm not sure how to else to access the stop function. when I attempt to use server.stop() in ~ServerThread() I get an error so The only way to not get the error is to instantiate it which obviously doesn't help but I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: perhaps retain `server` as a member of `ServerThread`?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work, throws a different error because when server is declared as TSimpleServer, It has to be followed by the (processor_t,server_transport,etc,etc)